# How I change the color with expression rdlc

Tags: c#, expression, rdlc

I need to change the color of my report.rdlc to `Red` when the `fields!Date.Value = "Sunday"` and the `fields!start.Value > 22` and `fields!finish.value < 5`. 
I tried to use

```
=IIf(Hour(fields!start.Value) > 22,"Red","Black")
```

but I don't know how I do the others cases. I am starting to report expressions now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be very similar to any other logical expression.  Just group all your conditions in parenthesis and if they are all true the action will happen so for your case try this...

```
=IIf(()Hour(fields!start.Value) > 22) AND 
    (Hour(fields!start.Value) < 5) AND 
    (fields!Date.Value = "Sunday")),"Red","Black")
```